# Keyboard input sometimes strange

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

My computer has a bug that appears about once a month, stays for a couple hours and goes away again. Most keyboard keys are unaffected but when I try to type "p", " ","c" or "b", nothing happens and more strangely, when I type "y", my computer screenshots (the regular "PrtSc" also still works however).

In addition to this the arrow keys work strangely, the left and right arrow keys only let me jump to the end and the beginning of a line and the up and down keys are even stranger, only moving the document view in LibreOffice writer, jumping five suggestions down or up in the firefox adress bar and in Text Editor jumping up and down 48 or 49 lines (most of the time).

My computer has both a linux and windows partition, but because the bug also appears in the boot menu, I can't select the windows one.

If anyone has any idea what could cause this, that would really help.

Comment: time to buy a new external keyboard i guess.

Comment: If it is appearing in your boot menu as well, then it doesn't sound like an OS issue.  You can try booting to a LiveCD/DVD/USB and test it that way as to help eliminate your installed OS as the problem.  To me it sounds like something may have been spilled in the keyboard at some point or if in a humid environment moisture is getting between the layers in the keyboard itself shorting out connections.

Comment: Would a humid environment also cause the wrong connections to be made and the keyboard to restore the correct keys hours after?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a hardware problem, or can use "showkey" to check
keycode like this :

$ sudo showkey

in my computer,
Y: 21
PrintScn: 99

Comment: But hardware problems don't usually just disappear and reappear, right?

Comment: what happen if test with "showkey" ?

Comment: The bug has subsided again, but it wll probably come eventually, using showkey did in fact show that key 99 was pressed when I pressed the Y key